# Broken display of this site

Tags: support

Roughly half of the time, the ME site does not display properly on the various devices I use. I get something that looks like this:

[image: bad display]

This happens quite a lot when using Internet Explorer on Windows 7 machines, less when using Chrome, and quite rarely on my iphone and ipad. The display might change from good to bad (and back again) even within a single session (on a single device). Does anyone know how to fix this?

If it matters, I'm in China, behind the Chinese GFW.

A comment below suggests that this is a problem with loading of the site's css file (which sounds reasonable, to me). Will the css file be downloaded to my local device? Does anyone  know where it goes? It only changes rarely, I assume, so it would make sense to cache it locally, wouldn't it?

Comment: What version[s] of MSIE are you using?

Comment: IE 9.0.8112. But, as I said, this also happens with Chrome, and (occasionally) using Safari on my iphone and ipad.

Comment: It looks like the css file isn't loading. The problem is most likely at your end.

Comment: @mrf. Yes, I though this might be related to CSS data. But I can't understand why this happens on several different devices on several different networks. Maybe a China thing? I can't remember if this ever happened to me when I'm traveling outside China.

Comment: @mrf. The css file should be downloaded to my local device, right? Do you know where it goes? It only changes rarely, I assume, so it would make sense to cache it locally, wouldn't it?